# Async the content in textbox

Tags: c#

I want to display the content asynchronously in textbox? Do anyone know the bug of my code listed below? I want to implement the text in textbox will be updated per second with new value? also i want to ask why checking the InvokeRequired each time before calling the invoke method for the controller?

```
        private void Counting(int Num)
    {

        int i = 0;
        string counter = null;
        while (i < Num)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            counter = string.Format(" {0}", i);
            tbxStatus.BeginInvoke(new UpdateStatusDelegate(UpdateStatus), new string[] { counter });
        }

    }

    public void UpdateStatus(string data)
    { 
        tbxStatus.Text += data;
    }

    public delegate void UpdateStatusDelegate(string data);

    public delegate void CountDelegate(int num);

    private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.Invoke(new CountDelegate(Counting), new object[] { 5 });
        }
        else
            Counting(5);
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your `InvokeRequired` test should be inside the delegate:

```
public void UpdateStatus(string data)
{
    if (this.tbxStatus.InvokeRequired)
    {
        UpdateStatusDelegate d = new UpdateStatusDelegate(UpdateStatus);
        this.Invoke(d, new object[] { data });
    }
    else
    {
        this.tbxStatus.Text = data;
    }
}
```

You can also make this a lot easier and cleaner looking if you use the following extension methods:

```
public static TResult SafeInvoke(this T isi, Func call) where T : ISynchronizeInvoke
{
    if (isi.InvokeRequired) {
        IAsyncResult result = isi.BeginInvoke(call, new object[] { isi });
        object endResult = isi.EndInvoke(result); return (TResult)endResult;
    }
    else
        return call(isi);
}

public static void SafeInvoke(this T isi, Action call) where T : ISynchronizeInvoke
{
    if (isi.InvokeRequired) isi.BeginInvoke(call, new object[] { isi });
    else
        call(isi);
}
```

So if I want to call a method that I have defined in my UI thread (like a method defined in your form instance) you can do so with the following code (with no need to create any delegates or anything):

```
formInstance.SafeInvoke(f => f.myFormMethod("parameter1","parameter2"));
```

in your case, you could do the following:

```
formInstance.SafeInvoke(f => f.UpdateStatus(myCounterInt.toString));
```

or something like that.

I've written about using this [on my blog](http://www.intelligiblebabble.com/generic-method-to-safely-perform-cross-thread-invoke/) but don't give me the credit as I was writing about [this CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/52752/Updating-Your-Form-from-Another-Thread-without-Cre)

Answer (score 1):

I have recently come to a similar problem.

I am writing a networked game and I wanted to append text to a text box I have, however I would get an error saying I was trying to change a windows form control from a different thread, thus causing a not safe thread. This is because I am using ASyncCallback on my server side.

I had this previously: (The console method is a simple method that gets a string and appends it to the textbox).

```
    console("message");
```

And to solve the problem I had to change it to this, solving the problem for now:

```
    this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { console("message"); });
```

Hopefully this helps others that come across this problem. It probably isn't the best approach possible but it did the trick for me.

Regards.